# Mysqld.exe загружает процессор на 100%. Что можно сделать?

Tags: mysql, администрирование

Mysqld.exe загружает процессор на 100%, и сервер умирает что можно сделать и как узнать что именно загружает его, какой запрос ? В администрировании скудные знания, объясните как можно проще пожалуйста !

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/slow-query-log.html